# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly in xammp

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql

Can anyone tell me why this is not working.

I am using XAMPP and get this error message while trying to install `SDK of Android Studio` that may be causing the problem.

Can anyone tell me why it is not working.

```
7:50:48 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
7:50:48 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
7:50:48 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
7:50:48 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
7:50:48 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
7:50:48 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
7:50:48 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall skype and reinstall xampp and then that worked